# SQL inline function with array input with 2 columns

Tags: sql, arrays, sql-server, inline-table-function

I have an inline function with an array input (dbo.Invoicenrs_table) like below, how can I extend this function to have a parameter more in the array input (I have extended the user defined table with an extra column) and the extra parameter must also be in the select.

```
FUNCTION  [dbo].[fn_SelectInvoices]
(
      @Invoice_Nrs dbo.Invoicenrs_table READONLY
)
RETURNS TABLE 

AS
RETURN
(      
      SELECT 
      [Invoice_Number] ,
      [Total_value]
    FROM Invoice WHERE [Invoice_Number] IN ( SELECT * from @Invoice_Nrs)
)
```

Comment: Microsoft SQL server

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are adding additional columns to your table type and you now need to match on multiple columns then you can just change the `WHERE` clause to an `INNER JOIN` to match any or all columns from the table parameter with your data table:

```
ALTER FUNCTION  [dbo].[fn_SelectInvoices]
(
      @Invoice_Nrs dbo.Invoicenrs_table READONLY
)
RETURNS TABLE 

AS
RETURN
(      
      SELECT 
      i.[Invoice_Number],
      i.[Col2],
      i.[Col3]
      i.[Total_value]
    FROM Invoice i
    INNER JOIN @Invoice_Nrs n ON i.[Invoice_Number] = n.[Invoice_Number
                             AND i.[Col2] = n.[Col2]
                             AND i.[Col3] = n.[Col3] --if you end up extending your table type further
                             AND ....
);
```

Comment: Great, that's it, thank you very much